# Group by a value if it exists otherwise group by another value of the same column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, grouping, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table like this

```
|  Id  | ExternalId | Type |     Date    | StatusCode |
-------------------------------------------------------
|  1   |   123      |  25  |  2020-01-01 |      A     |
|  2   |   123      |  25  |  2020-01-02 |      A     |
|  5   |   125      |  25  |  2020-01-01 |      A     |
|  6   |   125      |  25  |  2020-01-02 |      B     |
|  3   |   124      |  25  |  2020-01-01 |      B     |
|  4   |   124      |  25  |  2020-01-02 |      A     |
```

I need to take just one row for each `ExternalId` having the `Max(Date)` and having the `StatusCode = B` if B exists, otherwise the `StatusCode = A`

So, the expected result is

```
|  Id  | ExternalId | Type |     Date    | StatusCode |
-------------------------------------------------------
|  2   |   123      |  25  |  2020-01-02 |      A     | <--I take Max Date and the StatusCode of the same row
|  6   |   125      |  25  |  2020-01-02 |      B     | <--I take Max Date and the StatusCode of the same row
|  3   |   124      |  25  |  2020-01-02 |      B     | <--I take Max Date and B, even if the Status code of the Max Date is A
```

Here the query I have tried to write:

```
SELECT ExternalId, Type, EntityType, Max(Date) as Date
From MyTable
group by ExternalId, Type, EntityType
```

But I cannot finish it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirements, this could be, what you want:

```
SELECT ExternalId, Type,  MAX(Date) AS Date, MAX(StatusCode) AS StatusCode
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY ExternalId, Type
```

**Explanation**:

You want the Max of StatusCode, because B is greater than A. You want the Max of Date, no matter what StatusCode is shown. And you want it for each ExternalId. Therefore you have to Group by ExternalId.

Furthermore, you Need also the Type shown, and as it's no group function, the query has to be grouped by type either. It's no problem though, because type is dependent on ExternalId ( or at least in your example data, it is).

Comment: @Ciccio I have added an explanation. If you have further questions, you can ask.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand from your sql, you also need to group by Type and EntityType. If it’s correct, you can write max with condition for 'B' and another max for all rows and use those results in isnull or coalesce function like this:

```
Select
 t.ExternalId
,t.Type
,t.EntityType
,isnull(
  max(iif(t.StatusCode='B', t.Date, null))
 ,max(t.Date)
) as Date
From MyTable t
Group by 
 t.ExternalId
,t.Type
,t.EntityType
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to filter instead of aggregate. One solution is to use `row_number()`:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by ExternalId order by StatusCode desc, Date desc) rn
    from mytable t

) t
where rn = 1
```

The `order by` clause of `row_number()` puts rows with `StatusCode = 'B'` first, and then orders by descending date.

This works because `StatusCode` has only two values, and because `'B'`> `'A'`. If your real data has different values (or more than 2 values), then you would need something more explicit, like:

```
order by case when StatusCode = 'B' then 0 else 1 end, Date desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Query, Which can help you.

```
SELECT Externalid, MAX([Date]) as 'Date', MAX(StatusCode) 'StatusCode' from MyTable Group by Externalid
```

In your expected result, you have added the **id** column which cannot added here, if you want to have values from multiple rows.

Result will be

```
|123|2020-01-02|A|
|124|2020-01-02|B| 
|125|2020-01-02|B|
```